# How can I create an option to determine if a file is downloaded, opened in a new tab or the current tab?

Tags: sxa

I have created a download list, based on the `file list` component. I have a requirement to provide functionality that allows the content editor to determine whether, on click, a file should be downloaded, opened in a new tab or opened in the current tab.

I started by creating a `droplist` field on the template on which I set the `source` to an options folder I'd created containing the above choices.

From here, I intended to set rules on the file to determine how it should behave based on what was selected in the `droplist` but I realised that this functionality wasn't available in the rules engine.

Here's a picture of my variant, if it's useful:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What are your file types? PDF? jpg?

Comment: Have you looked into using the `download` attribute on a tags? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp

Comment: Yeah, I did have a look at the download attribute but I decided to see if there was a solution available within Sitecore due to the lack of legacy browser support. I don't think it's necessarily a huge issue, but I think my options seem to be limited, so I'll play around with your suggestion above. Cheers Richard

Comment: That won't work on IE, if you need support for that. There is nothing built into Sitecore to support this, and you need to set the `Content-Disposition` header to force a download: https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2015/11/16/force-download-of-media-files/. You could follow a similar solution for opening in a new tab by using a specific CSS class and Javascript.

Comment: Perfect, I'll have a play with this tomorrow. Many thanks for your response.